# how to remove ing from the end of word using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove "ing" from word, example i want "watching" become "watch" by removing "ing" from the end of the word. Using regex in java.

i use this pattern:

```
String pattern = "$ing";
```

and use it to remove:

```
String word = "watching";
word = word.replaceAll(pattern,"");
```

but the result is still "watching" not "watch"

Comment: And what will you do when sing turns into 's'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the dollar sign at the last, so that it matches the last `ing`. `$` is an anchor which represents End of the line.

**Example:**

```
System.out.println("watching".replaceAll("ing$", ""));
```

Comment: `System.out.println("watching".replaceFirst("ing$", ""));`

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want true end of the string use \z instead

```
ing\z
```